# How to get specific column from one table and all other data from other table in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is i want to print bill no,billdate,paty name,qty,amount,discount percentage,disc amount from purchase bill table along with i want to display item name according to the billno..how do i achieve this..i tried it with joining two table but it display the data repetitively..
Controller code:

```
    if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        $this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.date = purchaseitem.billdate','left outer');
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
  $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $data['query'] = $query;
```

View code:

```
<th>Bill No</th>
                                    <th>Bill Date</th>
                                    <th>Party Name</th>
                                    <th>Item Name</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                    <th>Disc %</th>
                                    <th>Disc Amt</th>
                                    <th>Bill Amount</th>
                                    <!--<th>Bill Amount</th>-->
                                </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <br>
                                                        <tbody>


                            <?php $rowcount = 1 ?>                          
                            <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['no'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['date'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['Prdtname'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['sqty'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['billtot'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['Disper'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['Disamt'];?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row['Grdtot'];?></td>
                                        <?php $rowcount +=1?>
                                        <br>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Help me to solve this problem...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the same table on line no. 7, that's why its repeating. May be,you want to join 'purchaseitem' table. If so,then change that line to this -

```
   $this->db->join('purchaseitem', 'purchasebill.date = purchaseitem.billdate','left outer');
```

Comment: I tried but i am getting not unique table database error

Comment: then maybe the primary key and foreign key you are using are not unique or have many similar rows from joining table.Try using unique `id` instead of date or name. like -

      `$this->db->join('purchaseitem', 'purchasebill.item_id=purchaseitem.id','left outer');`
        `$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.id=purchasebill.parmaster_id','left outer');`
NB:For this you must have to insert the `id` of the `purchaseitem` into `item_id` of `purchasebill` when you are inserting.Similarly `id` of a `parmaster` into `parmaster_id` accorging to the item and parmaster of the purchasebill.